# npm install not working due to invalid peer rxjs

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, angular

I'm trying to add the dependencies to a project I'm working on with `npm install`. However I keep getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\decraejo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.0
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package rxjs does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@4.2.3 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@4.2.3 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@4.2.3 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular-in-memory-web-api@0.3.2 wants rxjs@^5.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.21 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Dev\S\project\UserPortal\npm-debug.log
```

Some thing is wrong here, but can't tell what. First of all, it's telling me `peerinvalid Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.21 wants rxjs.....`, but my package.json doesn't even include angular 2.

Find bellow my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-aria": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-http": "0.0.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.4",
    "angular-messages": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-qrcode": "^7.2.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-route": ">1.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "~0.5.10",
    "jquery": "~3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-ui-router": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.4.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-minify": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rev": "^7.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-jquery": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/projectName.git"
  }
}
```

Comment: is It angularJs or angular2/4 ?

Comment: Try removing ``package-lock.json`` (if it exists in your root folder) and delete the entire ``node_modules`` folder. Then try to run ``npm install`` again. Also what is the version of your ``node`` and ``npm``?